# How do you debug dynamically loaded javascript in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

With Chrome, you can add

```
//# sourceURL=/js/dynamicFile.js
```

to enable the ability to debug a file that is loaded via ajax. But it does not appear to work on Firefox. Is there another method?